# Is it possible to have a number / float in JavaScript with two decimal values as zeros?

Tags: javascript

I would like to return the number, `15.00`, in a json payload: `{"theNumber" : 15.00}`. All my research on SO has suggested to do something like `parseFloat(15).toFixed(2)`, but this always returns a string and therefore does not solve the problem of returning `15.00` as a number / float.

Is it possible to return a number in JS with two decimal values as zeros?

Comment: No. Numeric types get auto-formatted. The zeroes don't matter in that case. If you want to display something, use a string.

Comment: where would you like to display it?

Comment: @NinaScholz I would like to respond with json, and I want this json to contain a key value - `theNumber: 15.00` -- i'll update the question to have this detail

Comment: `parseFloat(parseFloat(15).toFixed(2))`

Comment: `15 === 15.00`. If you want to *display* a number with two decimal points, it *must* be a string.

Comment: @robertjewell why does it matter how many zeroes does a number have? Again, if you want to display something, use a string, if you don't care (with JSON, you're generally just transferring information, so no users need to see it), then use the number as is.

Comment: This is not possible. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938008/trailing-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: @Ergec why do you thing that will do anything?

Comment: @vlaz it matters because what should front ends expect -- a number or an integer?

Comment: Then format it on the front end. I really don't see the issue here.

Comment: @vlaz I have tests that expect an integer but some times parseFloat returns a float. So when it's a float it breaks, but when its an integer it passes.

Comment: You realize that integers are numbers?

Comment: Yes I use  `+(parseFloat(15).toFixed(2))`

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Amy yeah I'm learning the word choice of the JS community. Basically I want parseFloat to do what it suggests -- turn `15` into a float.

Comment: @robertjewell integers are indeed numbers as Amy says. If you want an integer, then convert it to that. If you want a float, then convert it to that. Yes, a float CAN be an integer in JS, since technically neither exists - JS only has a single numeric type.

Comment: @robertjewell **ALL** numbers are the same type: float. If you want to *display* it a certain way, you do that with a string.

Comment: @robertjewell there aren't different types of numbers in JS. The difference between the integer `15` and the float `15.0` is literally nonexistent. They are the same number. Hence why JS drops the zeroes.

Comment: @gus27 has the correct duplicate in their comment, namely [Trailing zeros in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19938008/215552).

Comment: 15.00 inside a JSON object is just a value. And for javascript 15 and 15.00 are number literals and will have the same value for a number type.