# Keep trailing or leading zeroes on number

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to keep trailing or leading zeroes on a number in javascript, without using e.g. a string instead?

```
const leading  = 003;                 // literal, leading
const trailing = 0.10;                // literal, trailing
const parsed   = parseFloat('0.100'); // parsed or somehow converted

console.log(leading, trailing, parsed); // desired: 003 0.10 0.100
```

This question [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938008/trailing-zeros-in-javascript) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238701/why-javascript-parseint-ignoring-leading-zeros-in-the-string) [regularly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795335/add-trailing-zeros-to-an-integer-without-converting-to-string-in-js) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975680/how-to-retain-leading-zeroes-when-converting-string-to-number-in-javascript) (and still is), yet I don't have a place I'd feel comfortable linking to (did i miss it?).

Fully analogously would be keeping any other aspect of the representation a number literal was entered as, although asked nowhere near as often:

```
console.log(0x10); // 16 instead of potentially desired 0x10
console.log(1e1);  // 10 instead of potentially desired 1e1
```

---

For disambiguation, this is not about the following topics, for some of which I'll add links, as they might be of interest as well:

- Padding to a set amount of digits, formatting to some specific string representation, e.g. [How can i pad a value with leading zeroes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros), [How to output numbers with leading zeros in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-numbers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript), [How to add a trailing zero to a price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433122/how-to-add-a-trailing-zero-to-a-price-with-jquery)
- Why a certain string representation will be produced for some number by default, e.g. [How does JavaScript determine the number of digits to produce when formatting floating-point values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49384477/how-does-javascript-determine-the-number-of-digits-to-produce-when-formatting-fl)
- Floating point precision/accuracy problems, e.g. `console.log(0.1 + 0.2)` producing `0.30000000000000004`, see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), and [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: no..............

Comment: _"16 instead of potentially desired 0x10"_ -- `0x10` is the same thing as `16`. Also the same thing as `10000` in binary, the same thing as `sixteen` and the same as `XVI`, using roman numerals. Do not mistake the value (which is `16`, the number of squares on a 4x4 grid) with the many possible ways to represent it or describe it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A `number` stores no information about the representation it was entered as, or parsed from. It only relates to its mathematical value. Perhaps reconsider using a `string` after all.

---

If i had to guess, it would be that much of the confusion comes from the thought, that numbers, and their textual representations would either be the same thing, or at least tightly coupled, with some kind of bidirectional binding between them. This is not the case.

The representations like `0.1` and `0.10`, which you enter in code, are only used to generate a number. They are convenient names, for what you intend to produce, not the resulting value. In this case, they are names for the same number. It has a lot of other aliases, like `0.100`, `1e-1`, or `10e-2`. In the actual value, there is no contained information, about what or where it came from. The conversion is a one-way street.

When displaying a number as text, by default (`Number.prototype.toString`), javascript uses an algorithm to [construct one of the possible representations from a number](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring). This can only use what's available, the number value, also meaning it will produce the same results for two same numbers. This implies, that `0.1` and `0.10` will produce the same result.

Concerning the number<sup>1</sup> value, [javascript uses](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) [IEEE754-2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) float64<sup>2</sup>. When source code is being evaluated<sup>3</sup>, and a number literal is encountered, the engine will [convert the mathematical value the literal represents](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-mv) to a 64bit value, according to IEEE754-2019. This means any information about the original representation in code is lost<sup>4</sup>.

There is another problem, which is somewhat unrelated to the main topic. Javascript used to have an [octal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal), with a prefix of "0". This means, that `003` is being parsed as an octal, and would throw in strict-mode. Similarly, `010 === 8` (or an error in strict-mode), see [Why JavaScript treats a number as octal if it has a leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003770/why-javascript-treats-a-number-as-octal-if-it-has-a-leading-zero)

In conclusion, when trying to keep information about some representation for a number (including leading or trailing zeroes, whether it was written as decimal, hexadecimal, and so on), a `number` is not a good choice. For how to achieve some specific representation other than the default, which doesn't need access to the originally entered text (e.g. pad to some amount of digits), there are many other questions/articles, some of which were already linked.

---

[1]: Javascript also has [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), but while it uses a different format, the reasoning is completely analogous.

[2]: This is a simplification. Engines are allowed to use other formats internally (and do, e.g. to save space/time), as long as they are guaranteed to behave like an IEEE754-2019 float64 in any regard, when observed from javascript.

[3]: E.g. V8 would convert to bytecode earlier than evaluation, already exchanging the literal. The only relevant thing is, that the information is lost, before we could do anything with it.

[4]: Javascript gives the ability to operate on code itself (e.g. `Function.prototype.toString`), which i will not discuss here much. Parsing the code yourself, and storing the representation, is an option, but has nothing to do with how `number` works (you would be operating on code, a `string`). Also, i don't immediately see any sane reason to do so, over alternatives.