# Express - Retain scale of number even if 0

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

Using express, is it possible to return `0.0` (as a number) in response JSON?
What we are observing is, if the value is `0.0`, then Javascript is keeping only `0` and response JSON just has `0`.

We have a consuming system which is implying the data type of the json property based on data and it is wrongly implying the field to be Long instead of Decimal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep trailing or leading zeroes on number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616370/keep-trailing-or-leading-zeroes-on-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.toFixed()` to set the number of decimals. So for example

```js
var number = 0.000;
console.log(number); // <--- Prints only 0

var preciseNumber = parseFloat(0).toFixed(4); // 4 inside the .toFixed(4) is number of places after decimal point
console.log(preciseNumber); // <--- Prints '0.0000'
```

Do note that the `preciseNumber` is a string now.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. OP's wants to return `0.0` as a **number**.

Comment: Yeah looks like it isn't possible in Javascript

Answer (score -1):

you can use `.toFixed()` to set the number of decimals. So for example

```js
 

var number = 0.000;
console.log(number); // <--- Prints only 0

 

var preciseNumber = parseFloat(0).toFixed(4); // 4 inside the .toFixed(4) is number of places after decimal point
console.log(preciseNumber); // <--- Prints '0.0000'
```

Do note that the `preciseNumber` is a string now.

Comment: the exact same answer?